# CSS text-rendering Issue in chrome

Tags: html, css, text-rendering

there is a content in h3 tag, but it not appearing in chrome browser

## see the print screen  [image]

## =========

**If i hide   text-rendering:optimizelegibility  It will appear** 
see the print screen 
[image]

What are the role of "text-rendering:optimizelegibility" css property ? and why this content not appearing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `optimizeLegibility`: The browser emphasizes legibility over rendering
>   speed and geometric precision. This enables kerning and optional
>   ligatures.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering
I suggest overwrite css with: `text-rendering: auto`

Comment: why this content not appearing ?

Comment: it supposed to render text anti-alliased and more easy on the eyes. but it doesn't work well with Windows Chrome